The StretchDIBits interface has the following issues
int StretchDIBits(
  HDC        hdc,
  int        xDest,
  int        yDest,
  int        DestWidth,
  int        DestHeight,
  int        xSrc,
  int        ySrc,
  int        SrcWidth,
  int        SrcHeight,
  const VOID *lpBits,
  const BITMAPINFO *lpBitsInfo,
  UINT       iUsage,
  DWORD      dwRop
);


In StretchDIBits, pass negative values to BITMAPINFO.bmiHeaderbiHeight, and pass 0,0 to xSrc and ySrc. At this point, the coordinate origin is in the upper left corner. When either xSrc or ySrc is incremented by 1, the coordinate origin becomes in the lower left corner. How to solve this problem?
void CMFCTestDlg::DrawImage(const CString& imagePath, int32_t x, int32_t y)
{
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    m_pBitmap = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(imagePath);

    CStatic* pStaticCtrl = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);

    CRect staticRect;
    pStaticCtrl->GetClientRect(staticRect);

    HWND hWnd = pStaticCtrl->GetSafeHwnd();
    HDC hDC = ::GetDC(hWnd);
    HDC     hMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
    HGDIOBJ hOldBitMap = NULL;
    HBRUSH  hBkBrush = NULL;

    do {
        hMemDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
        if (NULL == hMemDC)
        {
            break;
        }

        RECT stWndRect;
        BOOL bGetClientRect = ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &stWndRect);
        if (FALSE == bGetClientRect)
        {
            break;
        }

        int nWndWidth = stWndRect.right - stWndRect.left + 1;
        int nWndHeight = stWndRect.bottom - stWndRect.top + 1;

        hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, nWndWidth, nWndHeight);
        if (NULL == hBitmap)
        {
            break;
        }

        ::SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);

        unsigned char chBkRed = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        unsigned char chBkGreen = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        unsigned char chBkBlue = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        COLORREF nBkColor = RGB(chBkRed, chBkGreen, chBkBlue);
        hBkBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(nBkColor);
        if (NULL == hBkBrush)
        {
            break;
        }

        unsigned char chBkRed = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        unsigned char chBkGreen = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        unsigned char chBkBlue = static_cast<unsigned char>(0xCC);
        COLORREF nBkColor = RGB(chBkRed, chBkGreen, chBkBlue);
        hBkBrush = ::CreateSolidBrush(nBkColor);
        if (NULL == hBkBrush)
        {
            break;
        }

        int nFillRect = ::FillRect(hMemDC, &stWndRect, hBkBrush);
        if (0 == nFillRect)
        {
            break;
        }

        Gdiplus::BitmapData bitmapData;
        Gdiplus::Rect rect(0, 0, m_pBitmap->GetWidth(), m_pBitmap->GetHeight());

        m_pBitmap->LockBits(&rect, Gdiplus::ImageLockModeRead, PixelFormat24bppRGB, &bitmapData);

        int bmpWidth = m_pBitmap->GetWidth();
        int bmpHeight = m_pBitmap->GetHeight();
        BITMAPINFO stBmpInfo;
        memset(&stBmpInfo, 0, sizeof(stBmpInfo));
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmpWidth;
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmpHeight;
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        stBmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

        ::SetStretchBltMode(hMemDC, COLORONCOLOR);

        int stride = bitmapData.Stride;
        BYTE* pBits = new BYTE[stride * bmpHeight];

        memcpy(pBits, bitmapData.Scan0, stride * bmpHeight);

        m_pBitmap->UnlockBits(&bitmapData);

        ::StretchDIBits(hMemDC,
            0,
            0,
            staticRect.Width(),
            staticRect.Height(),
            x,
            y,
            staticRect.Width(),
            staticRect.Height(),
            pBits,
            &stBmpInfo,
            DIB_RGB_COLORS,
            SRCCOPY);

        ::BitBlt(hDC, stWndRect.left, stWndRect.top,
            nWndWidth, nWndHeight,
            hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    } while (0);

    pStaticCtrl->ReleaseDC(pDC);
}

How to keep its coordinate origin always in the upper left corner position?
